# Round Robin Tennis Tournament Schedule

Tags: algorithms

I hope it is OK to ask this question here.

Can anyone help with the following please?

I need to work out a schedule for a tennis round robin competition.

It’s a rotating doubles game. Total number of players is 12.

We have 2 courts so 8 players playing at once with four sitting out at a time.

So in summary we have:

- 2 courts
- 12 players
- 3 hours
- each game consists of 20 minutes

We have 3 hours but would like to leave 15 - 20 mins free which will give a little time between games.

I need a schedule of games where everyone has a random different partner for each game and everyone gets to play the same number of games within our approx 2 hour 40 minute time slot.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament ?

Comment: When you say random partners for each game, does this allow the possibility that two specific players would be partners in more than one game (due to random chance); or would a given player definitely have a different partner in each game they played?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the information I appreciate it, I will take a look.

Comment: Hello paw88789, Thanks very much for your reply. Sorry I should have added the player needs to have a different partner in each game they play.