# How to organise a robin robin where 8 teams play 8 games with each team playing each other team once plus one team twice with only 4 games at a time.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am organising a sports day with 8 teams (T1-T8) and 8 activities (A1-A8) over 8 time slots (t1-t8). Each team can only do each activity once and can only play every other team once expect for repeating 1 fixture (out of necessity). Is this possible? And how would this be formatted in an grid looking something like the image linked below? Obviously each team can only be doing 1 activity at a time.

[Sample Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpfrE.png)

Comment: Similar question asked [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482247/305862). Many other answers on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a schedule that works:

| ${}$ | T0 | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 | T7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A0** | 0/2 | 5/6 |  | 1/4 | 3/7 |  |  |  |
| **A1** |  | 1/3 | 6/7 |  | 2/5 | 4/0 |  |  |
| **A2** |  |  | 2/4 | 7/0 |  | 3/6 | 5/1 |  |
| **A3** |  |  |  | 3/5 | 0/1 |  | 4/7 | 6/2 |
| **A4** | 7/3 |  |  |  | 4/6 | 1/2 |  | 5/0 |
| **A5** | 6/1 | 0/4 |  |  |  | 5/7 | 2/3 |  |
| **A6** |  | 7/2 | 1/5 |  |  |  | 6/0 | 3/4 |
| **A7** | 4/5 |  | 0/3 | 2/6 |  |  |  | 7/1 |

This schedule can be described concisely as follows:

> Number the activities, rounds, and people from $0$ to $7$. 
> For each $i\in \{0,\dots,7\}$, the $i^\text{th}$ activity is played by
>
> - teams number $i+\color{red}0$ and $i+\color{red}2$ in round $i+\color{blue}0$,
> - teams number $i+\color{red}5$ and $i+\color{red}6$ in round $i+\color{blue}1$,
> - teams number $i+\color{red}1$ and $i+\color{red}4$ in round $i+\color{blue}3$,
> - teams number $i+\color{red}3$ and $i+\color{red}7$ in round $i+\color{blue}4$,
>
> where all addition is modulo $8$.

I got the idea to look for a schedule with this special form from [Anders Kaseorg's solution to this related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4224205), and I just wrote a computer program to check all possibilities for the red and blue parameters until it found one that produced a valid schedule.